# Proxy settings with fiddler

Tags: html, internet-explorer, debugging, proxy, fiddler

I am using fiddler2 and working behind a corporte proxy. Whenever my fiddler crashes or shutdown prematurely, it **doesn't resets my proxy settings.** So i have set the proxy again and set the IE exceptions again.

```
Fiddler version : v2.3.7.4
```

I want my proxy settings to be normal when my fiddler crashes. How can i do that?

Comment: To start, you should probably stop using a Fiddler version that is several YEARS out-of-date. And if you can still crash it, you should report the bug.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I used to update regularly for my personal use. But my employer don't allow me to do so. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is really annoying, you can create a .reg file to restore default settings, simply execute regedit and navigate to:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
```

Keys to export:

```
"MigrateProxy"
"ProxyEnable"
"ProxyHttp1.1"
"ProxyServer"
"ProxyOverride"
```

If Fiddler crashes again, just double click the generated .reg file and all settings will be reset.

See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819961

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is the best solution, maybe more like a workaround, but it always works on my machine:

1. Turn on fiddler again
2. Turn off fiddler.

It should fix the problem because at the time you turn fiddler off it resets your proxy settings to the ones you were using originaly